# Windows update broke programs

Tags: windows-10, automatic-update

I'm at a loss about what to do. There was a windows 10 OS update forced to computer a couple weeks ago. Now various programs can't access files in MyDocuments and others can't access the DVD drives. I'm using windows defender and no other antivirus programs. I did notice that windows defender blocked access to a Steam folder so when I added that under exclusions in the settings Steam worked again. But programs like VLC can't access the DVD drives. Been searching on the internet but haven't found anyone complaining about this. I've tried disabling windows defender but that didn't work. Anyone having this problem as well and anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Update: So even though turning off windows defender didn't work, I turned off "Controlled folder access". Guess that doesn't turn off by turning off real time protection. Anyway when I do that, programs are able to access the DVD drives again. It's suppose to block only unfriendly applications from only folders in my user folder. Don't know how it classifies a program as unfriendly or why blocking access to my user folders doesn't let them access the DVD drives. Maybe this was caused by the April security update. Odd.

Comment: You can rollback to a previous version of Windows. You are apparently running on the Windows insider track because the April 2018 update is not generally available and has not been pushed on anyone. So, you have opted to be a guinea pig.

Comment: Don't know how that happened. Never signed up for that. I looked for that rollback option but one website said it goes away after 10 days. Any other ways of rolling back.

Comment: Yes, you can reinstall Windows fresh. https://www.howtogeek.com/274780/how-to-switch-from-windows-10s-insider-preview-back-to-stable-without-reinstalling/

Comment: I looked and am not part of the insiders program. I do have a restore point from April 12. Would using that fix it? I think it's from before the update.

Comment: I'm on version 1709

Comment: Are you sure you’ve updated to the April 2018 build of Windows 10? Or are you just referring to the April 2018 cumulative update? Your question is confusing because the new release of Windows 10 coming Monday is called April 2018 update. The cumulative update is just a typical security and general fix release. It should not be causing any significant trouble. How do you know the problems are because of the update? Your question is really too broad to answer. It’s unlikely the update caused these issues and any number of other things could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

barn door issue.

I would suggest you make a full system image backup EVERY time you update anything on your system drive. This needs to be made to a different HDD, a different partition on the same disc removes the option of recovering from a disc failure, and they DO happen. Surprise: you are down for the count! Another drive on the internal system will be faster. I'd suggest minimum of 500GB. As such backups take a lot of room. !TB would be better, maybe.

There are freebie apps that can do this easily. My own favorite is EASUS TODO. I'm not shilling for them. I do use it and have several paid for licences.

With a system backup from 2 weeks ago and an update or whatever causes a problem, you can be back in business inside of an hour. Oh, DO make a bootable USB thumb drive using the EASUS app...still freebie version, I believe. because sometimes you can't boot on the corrupted system drive any more. *another reason for NOTG using a partition on the system drive for the backups. A USB 3 external backup is a bit slower, but has the advantage of being remote from the system. With the flash drive version of the EASUS program and an external drive with the latest backup, you are close to being bullet proof. Assuming the USB works, which it should because the drivers ought to be loaded before windows, I think.

Hope this helps.